# How to determine if a string "ends with" another string in R?

Tags: r, string, ends-with

I want to filter out the rows of a table which contain '*' in the string value of the column. Checking just that column.

```
 string_name = c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "dddd*", "eee*eee")

 zz <- sapply(tx$variant_full_name, function(x) {substrRight(x, -1) =="*"})
 Error in FUN(c("Agno I30N", "VP2 E17Q", "VP2 I204*", "VP3 I85F", "VP1 K73R",  : 
   could not find function "substrRight"
```

The 4th value of zz should be TRUE by this.

in python there is endswith function for strings [ string_s.endswith('*') ]
Is there something similar to that in R ?

Also, is it problem because of '*' as a character as it means any character ? grepl also not working.

```
> grepl("*^",'dddd*')
[1] TRUE
> grepl("*^",'dddd')
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You can escape the `*` `grepl("\\*",'dddd*')`. To find strings that end with a `*` you can use `grepl("\\*$", string_name)`

Answer (score 22):

Base now contains `startsWith` and `endsWith`.  Thus the OP's question can be answered with `endsWith`:

```
> string_name = c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "dddd*", "eee*eee")
> endsWith(string_name, '*')
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This is much faster than `substring(string_name, nchar(string_name)) == '*'`.

Answer (score 15):

`*` is a [**quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in regular expressions. It tells the regular expression engine to attempt to match the preceding token "zero or more times". To match a literal, you need to precede it with two backslashes or place inside of a character class `[*]`. To check if the string ends with a specific pattern, use the [end of string `$` **anchor**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
> grepl('\\*$', c('aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'dddd*', 'eee*eee'))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can simply do this without implementing a regular expression in base R:

```
> x <- c('aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'dddd*', 'eee*eee')
> substr(x, nchar(x)-1+1, nchar(x)) == '*'
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 8):

This is simple enough that you don't need regular expressions.

```
> string_name = c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "dddd*", "eee*eee")
> substring(string_name, nchar(string_name)) == "*"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

I use something like this:

```
strEndsWith <- function(haystack, needle)
{
  hl <- nchar(haystack)
  nl <- nchar(needle)
  if(nl>hl)
  {
    return(F)
  } else
  {
    return(substr(haystack, hl-nl+1, hl) == needle)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a tidyverse solution:

```
string_name = c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "dddd*", "eee*eee")
str_sub(string_name, -1) == "*"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

It has the benefits of being much more readable and can also be changed easily if a different location needs to be checked.

Comment: Could you please turn this into a reproducible answer, applied to the question?