# Removing patterns in R

Tags: r

I have a character string that looks like below and I want to delete lines that doesn't have any value after '_'.
How do I do that in R?

```
 [985] "Pclo_"                "P2yr13_ S329"         "Basp1_ S131"         
 [988] "Stk39_ S405"          "Srrm2_ S351"          "Grin2b_ S930"        
 [991] "Matr3_ S604"          "Map1b_ S1781"         "Crmp1_"              
 [994] "Elmo1_"               "Pcdhgc5_"             "Sp4_"                
 [997] "Pbrm1_"               "Pphln1_"              "Gnl1_ S33"           
[1000] "Kiaa1456_"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a string "ends with" another string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188663/how-to-determine-if-a-string-ends-with-another-string-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
grep("_$", v1, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

---

Or `endsWith`

```
v1[!endsWith(v1, "_")]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substring` to get the last character in the vector and select if it is not `"_"`.

```
x <- c("Pclo_","P2yr13_ S329","Basp1_ S131")
x[substring(x, nchar(x)) != '_']
#[1] "P2yr13_ S329" "Basp1_ S131"
```

Last character can be extracted using regex as well with `sub` :

```
x[sub('.*(.)$', '\\1', x) != '_']
```